# Where should I place this condition?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For the last step of this project, I want the growing circle to stop when it collides with another circle. The `isOnCircle` function already checks for this successfully when creating a new circle. However, when adding the condition `!isOnCircle` to my `grow()` function (line 61) it prevents any new circles from being added.

```
function grow() {
    var a = circles[circles.length - 1];
    if (!isOnCircle(a)){
        a.radius += 1;
    }}
```

Perhaps the circle is being created first, then in the check for collision, it's colliding with itself. Where else could I put the !isOnCircle check so that it gets checked at every radius increase and stops the grow function then?
[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/90/)

```
//set up canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var circles = [];

//create circle
function create(location) {
    circles.push({
        x: location.x,
        y: location.y,
        radius: 10,
        color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
    });
}

//figure out mouse position
var rect = document.getElementById("canvas").getBoundingClientRect();
// Get canvas offset on page
var offset = {
    x: rect.left,
    y: rect.top
};

function isOnCanvas(a) {
    if ((a.x >= 0 && a.x <= rect.width) && (a.y >= 0 && a.y <= rect.height)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isOnCircle(a) {
    var i = 0,
        l = circles.length,
        x, y, d, c;
    for (; i < l; ++i) {
        c = circles[i];
        x = a.x - c.x;
        y = a.y - c.y;
        d = (a.radius || 10) + c.radius;
        if (x * x + y * y <= d * d) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// draw all circles
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var p = circles[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

//make last drawn circle 1px bigger
function grow() {
    var a = circles[circles.length - 1];
        a.radius += 1;
}

//find percentage of canvas filled in
var totalSpace = canvas.width * canvas.height;
var totalFilled = function () {
    total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        var p = circles[i];
        total += Math.PI * Math.pow(p.radius, 2);
    }
    return total;
    console.log(total);
}

    function findPercentage() {
        return (totalFilled() / totalSpace) * 100;
    }

    function updateInfo() {
        percentage = findPercentage();
        document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = "You've filled in " + percentage.toFixed(1) + "%";
    }

    //do all the stuff
var animate = function () {
    grow();
    draw();
    updateInfo();
}

//put this outside function so we can stop it later
var growLoop;

window.onmousedown = function (e) {
    // get event location on page offset by canvas location
    var location = {
        x: e.pageX - offset.x,
        y: e.pageY - offset.y
    };

    if (isOnCanvas(location) && !isOnCircle(location)) {
        create(location);
        draw();
        updateInfo();
        growLoop = setInterval(animate, 100);
    }
};

window.onmouseup = function () {
    clearInterval(growLoop);
}
window.onmouseout = function () {
    clearInterval(growLoop);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly did you add the condition? You might also highlight "line 61" with a comment…

Comment: Added the proposed function changes, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's colliding with itself.

Probably. You definitely should avoid that in the collision detection:

```
function isOnCircle(a) {
    var l = circles.length,
        x, y, d, c;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        c = circles[i];
        if (a == c)   // add these
            continue; // two lines!
        x = a.x - c.x;
        y = a.y - c.y;
        d = (a.radius || 10) + c.radius;
        if (x * x + y * y <= d * d) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is colliding with itself. Since you know the current circle will always be the last one in circles you can modify isOnCircle like this:

```
l = circles.length - 1,
```

so that it won't check against the current circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeAGU/91/

Comment: This have the same effect as Bergi's check for a==c above, right? Trying both out now.

Comment: Yeah, it should be the same. I'm just not a fan of the continue statement.

Comment: If the collision test is not only done after the creation of the circle (but e.g. also when growing it, like the OP plans to do), this will not work any more.

Comment: @scf1001: If you don't like `continue`, you could as well have written `if (a != c) { x = a.x-c.x; … } /* until the end of the loop body */`

Comment: Yep, fair point, but we know the current circle (the one which is growing) will be the last item in the circles array. By avoiding looping through that item, we avoid checking against the current circle. It will still work.

Comment: It works guys, thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/goldrunt/SeAGU/95/ But now I see the percentage can get above 100% unless I constrain the circles to the canvas! Always one more thing to add...